# How to repair damaged memory card without data loss?

Tags: sd-card

I have a memory card in SDHC format with a capacity of 8.00 GB, on which my very important photos are stored.

When I connect it to the appropriate slot in the memory card reader, I get a warning that the card must be formatted before use. However, when I try to do that, after a while I get this error: "Windows was unable to complete the format".

When I view the card in DISKMGMT.MSC, I only see 1.00 GB of the original capacity of 8.00 GB! (There are no other hidden partitions). Every time I try to delete a partition on the card I get this error: "The semaphore timeout period has expired". I can't use CHKDSK because the card has either an unknown file system or no file system (RAW).

I suspect there are bad sectors on the card and there is also something strange rattling inside the card, otherwise the card is not physically damaged in any way. However, this damage happened out of nowhere, the card always worked fine before.

What can I do to repair the card and regain access to the photos that are probably still on it? I tried various data recovery programs but none of them found anything. I also don't know how to physically open the card, and also how to repair any internal damage.

Thank you very much for any help you can give.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry.  A card like this is beyond any data recovery in the shape it is in (possible exception of a local recovery agency).

And if you cannot format, then the card is gone. Just replace it.

Always keep extra backups of important items.